# How to speed up pandas.rolling weighted_average or other function?

Tags: python, pandas, rolling-computation

I want to calculate the weighted average for a long array.

which rolling in a fixed-size window.

For example:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: a = pd.Series(range(int(1e8)))

In [5]: import numpy as np; w = np.array(list(range(10)));

In [6]: a.rolling(10).apply(lambda x: (x * w).sum())
```

as i tried, this is very slow, I read some blog, sometimes it can be speeded up by:

```
 a.rolling(10).apply(np.argmax, engine='numba', raw=True)
```

but this can only be used in build-in function, for some customed function, seems not work.

do you know how to make it standable in costing time?

Comment: How much system memory(RAM) do you have?

Comment: @ShubhamSharma 128G

Answer (score 1):

#### Solution with [`np.convolve`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.convolve.html)

We can convolve the weights `w` over the series `a` using the `valid` mode convolution operation, essentially this has the same effect as calculating the rolling weighted sum.

```
s = np.convolve(a, w[::-1], 'valid')
s = [np.nan] * (len(w) - 1) + list(s)
```

#### Solution with [`sliding_window_view`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view.html)

Alternatively, we can also use `sliding_window_view` to speed up the rolling weighted sum computation

```
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import sliding_window_view

s = (sliding_window_view(a, len(w)) * w).sum(1)
s = [np.nan] * (len(w) - 1) + list(s)
```

##### Timings

```
a = pd.Series(range(int(1e4)))

%%timeit
s = np.convolve(a, w[::-1], 'valid')
s = [np.nan] * (len(w) - 1) + list(s)
# 1000 loops, best of 5: 626 µs per loop

%%timeit
s = (sliding_window_view(a, len(w)) * w).sum(1)
s = [np.nan] * (len(w) - 1) + list(s)    
# 1000 loops, best of 5: 1.2 ms per loop

%%timeit
s = a.rolling(10).apply(lambda x: (x * w).sum())
# 1 loop, best of 5: 3.6 s per loop
```

As it is evident from the performance test using **`np.convolve` is about `5750x` faster**, while using **`sliding_window_view` is around `2880x` faster** compared to the pandas `rolling` + `apply` method.

Comment: @nick Does this answered your question?